# How to modify lightgbm for my custom loss functions?

Tags: lightgbm

Which files should be change while adding my own custom loss function? I know I can add my objective and gradient/hessian computation in ObjectiveFunction,  just wondering if there is anything else I need to do or if there are other alternatives for custom loss functions.

Answer (score 3):

According to demo files in [lightGBM early stopping example](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/R-package/demo/early_stopping.R),

Setting objective function as:

```
# User define objective function, given prediction, return gradient and second order gradient
# This is loglikelihood loss
logregobj <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  preds <- 1 / (1 + exp(-preds))
  grad <- preds - labels
  hess <- preds * (1 - preds)
  return(list(grad = grad, hess = hess))
}
```

Setting error function as:

```
# User defined evaluation function, return a pair metric_name, result, higher_better
# NOTE: when you do customized loss function, the default prediction value is margin
# This may make buildin evalution metric not function properly
# For example, we are doing logistic loss, the prediction is score before logistic transformation
# The buildin evaluation error assumes input is after logistic transformation
# Take this in mind when you use the customization, and maybe you need write customized evaluation function
evalerror <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  err <- as.numeric(sum(labels != (preds > 0.5))) / length(labels)
  return(list(name = "error", value = err, higher_better = FALSE))
}
```

And then you can run lightgbm as:

```
bst <- lgb.train(param,
                 dtrain,
                 num_round,
                 valids,
                 objective = logregobj,
                 eval = evalerror,
early_stopping_round = 3)
```